# vue not getting props value in child component under mounted or created

Tags: vue.js

I have below code. I am undefined while printing src in mounted. Is there anything I am missing?

Parent.vue

```
 <Child :src='this.src'/>
```

Child.vue

```
<input type="file" name="files" :href="src"/>


<script>

  export default {
     props: [
      'src',
     ],
   mounted(){
    console.log('mounted ' + this.src);
   },
</script>
```

Comment: did you try passing it to computed first and then use it in mounted?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to write "this" in Template/HTML section

so in Parent component

```
 <Child :src='src'/>
```

child component should remain the same.

Comment: Its same. It works on 2nd load. On firstload, I am not getting the value in mounted

Comment: should be working, try to refresh and check again please

Comment: can you maybe share more code of the `Parent.vue` ? it looks like the problem lies in how `src` in `Parent.vue` is populated

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are already using the prop `src` where the prop is not yet available or should I say the prop has no value yet when you printed it in mounted.

In fact that prop has a value already when you try to view it Vue Debugger. it's just because you are printing it in mounted where the prop is not yet existing. Put a condition to your component like this.

```
<input v-if="src" type="file" name="files" :href="src"/>
```

Comment: My question is why its not getting the variable on first load but its there on second load.

Comment: because you are using already the prop where the prop is not yet ready to use.

Comment: so the solution would be? v-if does not solve my issue.

Comment: Is the issue that `src` is undefined when you log it in `mounted`?